# Matching a regex against another regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, puppet

I wonder if there is an elegant way to match one pre-compiled regex against another? I suppose not, but still decided to ask.

Say, I want to find all nodes in Puppet's node.pp corresponding to a particular pattern. The problem is, the node names can be (and usually are) defined as regexes themselves. For example, one may need to find all nodes in 'production' environment, which all by convention start with 'p' followed by either 1 or 2 `/^p[12].+$/`. In other words,

```
p(1|2)proxy-[1-4].domain.lan
p1smtp-[1-2].domain.lan
p[12]what-not-[1-8].domain.lan
```

should match, while

```
q(1|2)proxy-[1-4].domain.lan
q(1|2)smtp-[1-2].domain.lan
q(1|2)what-not-[1-8].domain.lan
```

should not.

The target strings (if compiled as regexes) are all sub-cases of the more general expression. So I wonder, if there's any shortcut?

Of course, one can match the node names as literal strings including all 'regex' variations – shouldn't be hard in that particular case.

Comment: So which regex do you want to compare with which other? Are you saying you want to check whether what matches, say, `p(1|2)proxy-[1-4].domain.lan` also matches `^p[12].+$`? Where are these regexes coming from? Particularly the second set.

Comment: @Borodin: I need a (more general) regex to match other, more specific regex-like strings. It would be easier to do, if regex-like strings could be in some fashion interpreted as regexes rather than strings. The example is taken from Puppet's node.pp file. The question is now answered, see below.

Answer (score 4):

“If you can think of it, there's a CPAN module for that”. It is like the rule 34 of Perl.

So there actually is [Regexp::Compare](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCompare) that given two regexp strings can (sometimes) decide if one regexp matches a true subset of the other. Note that for this to be true, I anchored your input regexp at the start. Then `is_less_or_equal` will return true if `$metarx` can match all strings that `$rx` matches.

```
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;
use Regexp::Compare qw(is_less_or_equal);

my @rx = (
  'p(1|2)proxy-[1-4].domain.lan',
  'p1smtp-[1-2].domain.lan',
  'p[12]what-not-[1-8].domain.lan',
  'q(1|2)proxy-[1-4].domain.lan',
  'q(1|2)smtp-[1-2].domain.lan',
  'q(1|2)what-not-[1-8].domain.lan',
);
my $metarx = '^p[12]';

for my $rx (@rx) {
  say "/$metarx/ ≥ /^$rx/ ?\t", is_less_or_equal("^$rx", $metarx) ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

Output:

```
/^p[12]/ ≥ /^p(1|2)proxy-[1-4].domain.lan/ ?    yes
/^p[12]/ ≥ /^p1smtp-[1-2].domain.lan/ ?         yes
/^p[12]/ ≥ /^p[12]what-not-[1-8].domain.lan/ ?  yes
/^p[12]/ ≥ /^q(1|2)proxy-[1-4].domain.lan/ ?    no
/^p[12]/ ≥ /^q(1|2)smtp-[1-2].domain.lan/ ?     no
/^p[12]/ ≥ /^q(1|2)what-not-[1-8].domain.lan/ ? no
```

I believe this does what you had in mind. (Note: don't use regex objects, but just plain strings—this module may have difficulties with some stringifications)

Comment: Yes, and thank you, this is what I've had in mind exactly. Well, my first thought was some bleeding-edge built-in feature, but if a CPAN module works – fine by me!